# Saving the font from a text pane java

Tags: java, text, netbeans, fonts, text-editor

I'm making a Text Editor as a side project and as of now I'm struggling by saving and loading the text's font letter, color, and decoration; in other words, I can only save a plain text. My question is, how can I save and load all of these?

```
private void Edit() {//This is the method where the program edits the text
    StyledDocument doc = this.tpText.getStyledDocument();
    Style estilo = this.tpText.addStyle("miEstilo", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(estilo, colour); //Color
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(estilo, fontLetter);//Letter
    StyleConstants.setFontSize(estilo, size);//Size
    StyleConstants.setBold(estilo, bold);//Bold
    StyleConstants.setItalic(estilo, italics);//Italics
    StyleConstants.setUnderline(estilo, underline);//Underline
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(this.tpText.getSelectionStart(), this.tpText.getSelectionEnd() - this.tpText.getSelectionStart(), this.tpText.getStyle("miEstilo"), true);//The only text that will be edited is the one that the user highlights
}

private void comboxFontsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//This is one of the methods in which the program edits the text                                            
        this.fontLetter = (String) this.comboxFonts.getSelectedItem();
        Edit();
}
private void mibtnSaveAsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//Save as... menu item button                                            
        int saveResult = fileSelect.showSaveDialog(null);
            if (saveResult == fileSelect.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                saveFile(fileSelect.getSelectedFile(), this.tpText.getText());
                this.mibtnSave.setEnabled(true);
            }
    }
public void saveFile(File file, String contents) {//Save File
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    String filePath = file.getPath();

    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
        writer.write(contents);
        writer.close();
        this.tpText.setText(contents);
        currentFile = file;
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void openFile(File file) {//Load File
    if (file.canRead()) {

        String filePath = file.getPath();
        String fileContents = "";

        if (filePath.endsWith(".txt")) {
            try {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    fileContents += sc.nextLine();
                }

                sc.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            }
            this.tpText.setText(fileContents);
            currentFile = file;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Only .txt files are supported.");

        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not open file...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got your question right, but if your trying to save the style besides the plain text you may do the following.
save all style attributes in another file next to the text file and you can restore it when you open the text file.

Comment: I was thinking about that also, but here is the problem: let's say the text is "hello world" the "hello" part is bold while "world" is italic. "**hello** _world_" I want to know how can I save and load the text like that.

Comment: Ok let me make suggest something to you my friend..
when any user tries to make a text styling save that styling in a string then write it to a file right next to the saved plain text.
example:
when the bold or italic button is clicked to make hello bold and world italic your string should be something like:
"line X col Y word 'hello' bold"
where `X and Y` are the position of the word in text